# Interface inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have an interface called **IStrategy**:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
}
```

I have another interface called **IClickStrategy** that inherits from **IStrategy**. It has a method called *GetClicks()*:

```
public interface IClickStrategy : IStrategy
{
   void GetClicks(string[] args);
}
```

And a class that inherits from **IClickStrategy** and implements the *GetClicks()* method:

```
public class UnionenClicksController : IClickStrategy
{
    Models.DMDelivery.Unionen model;
    Logger logger;

    public UnionenClicksController()
    {
        this.model = new Models.DMDelivery.Unionen();
        this.logger = new Logger();
    }

    public void GetClicks(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

On my main method, depending on the type of strategy I would like to decide what to do.So before everything I have:

```
IStrategy strategy = null;
```

And then if the input parameters wanted to get clicks information I would like to invoke the GetClicks function from my class **UnionenClicksController()**.

[image]

But as can be seen, I cannot see the *GetClicks()* function. However if I change my strategy to an **IClickStrategy**, then it will see my GetClicks. But that's not what I want because I may have a different strategy other than clicks and I don't want to declare it at the beginning of my main method.

What is it that I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You can't set a public on a interface method, are you running a custom compiler that skips the interface in case of errors?

Answer (score 1):

`IStrategy` doesn't contain `GetClicks`, it is to be found in `IClickStrategy` interface.

Change

```
IStrategy strategy = null;
```

to

```
IClickStrategy strategy = null;
```

You can also try casting it to proper interface,

if you are sure that it implements correct interface:

```
((IClickStrategy)strategy).GetClicks();
```

if you are unsure:

```
var s = strategy as IClickInterface;
if (s != null)
{
    s.GetClicks();
}
```

Comment: "But that's not what I want because I may have a different strategy other than clicks and I don't want to declare it at the beginning of my main method."

Comment: @Daniel Daranas Then use generics if you at runtime don't know how to cast them. Or identify the class somehow through reflection.

Comment: @Deukalion I was just quoting the OP's words about why he can't use IClickStrategy in the first place.

Comment: @walkhard I tried both your solutions and neither worked alas. In both cases I get errors and VS does not allow me to run the app.

Comment: @Pedram why is that, what error do you get? I tried compiling and running it and it works.

Comment: @walkhard It works if I declare strategy as IClickStrategy in the beginning. But does not work if my strategy is an IStrategy.

Comment: @Pedram like I said, I've successfully compiled and run it, without errors. What error do you get? In what way it isn't working for you (null, exception etc)?

Comment: @walkhard the error is a NullPointerException because we set strategy to null I suppose.

Comment: @Pedram I suspect that you set it to null somewhere, take a look at [this working code snippet](http://ideone.com/YTAurl)

Comment: @walkhard you are setting the strategy in the beginning of the program as IStrategy s = new UnionenClicksController(); the thing is in the beginning I should decided whether I'm going to have a click strategy or something else. Therefore I set my strategy to null and then if the user requested a click strategy I would like my strategy to instantiate a new UnionenClicksController object and run it's GetClicks() method. And not right from the start of the program.

Comment: @walkhard yes I'm setting it as null as I've written and when we cast it to an IClickStrategy like that it throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either cast for each case, or have a virtual method in `IStrategy` that chooses the right method.

The latter solution is impossible if an object implement several strategies.

Comment: When I create a new strategy object on each case and then call its GetClicks method it works:

Comment: IClickStrategy strategy = new UnionenClicksController(); strategy.GetClicks(args);  but can you elaborate on your virtual method solution?

Comment: The virtual method solution: `interface IStrategy { void GetWhatever(string[]); }` and `class ClickStrategy : IClickStrategy { public void GetWhatever(string[] args) { return GetClicks(args); } public void GetClicks(string[] args) { ... } }`

Comment: But frankly, I recommend Preet Sangha's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
IStrategy strategy = null;

.
.
.  later on you find that you need to see if it contains a IClickStrategy ..
.

IClickStrategy clicker = strategy as IClickStrategy;

if(clicker != null) {
  clicker.GetClicks(...);
}
```

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, you may or may not need an `else { new MyDefaultClickStrategy().GetClicks(...); }`

Comment: @Preet Sangha: this looks good but it gives me a NullPointerException again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
IClickStrategy strategy = null;
```

because UnionenClicksController does not inherit IStrategy.

Comment: I don't want to do that because my strategy may not be always a click strategy. So I do not want to declare it that way. Depending on the input argument in the switch statement I will realize weather I should run a click strategy or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you do. But the compiler doesn't know that. You just *told* him, you want to treat `strategy` as an `IStrategy`. You were very explicit about that. Now...

Don't confuse the name `strategy` with your `UnionenClicksControler` object - it is just a name for the object. And the name has a type. If you want to get at the `GetClicks()` method, just do:

```
(strategy as IClickStrategy).GetClicks(args);
```

I have not tried this myself yet, since I haven't got around to, but doing

```
dynamic strategy;
```

might also solve your problem... but you probably forfeit any IntelliSense magic...

Comment: Null reference exception in either cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
if(strategy is IClickStrategy)
    (strategy as IClickStrategy).GetClicks();
```

Technically you need to check for the type of the object first, then cast it in order to see the inheriting interface's method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers but I found two solutions to my problem:

First, is to not use the line:

```
IStrategy strategy = null;
```

And postpone it until after every switch statement and then declare the strategy as a IClickStrategy.

Second, if I want to keep my *IStrategy strategy = null;* line I moved the GetClicks method one level up in my IStrategy interface and gave it a more general name: **GetItems**.

And now my switch case looks like this:

```
case "GETCLICKSUNIONEN":
    strategy = new UnionenClicksController();
    strategy.GetItems(args);                            
    break;
```